# Make requests for a list of objects in Graphql response

Tags: graphql

Let's say that I have the following query schema:

```
schema {
    query: Query
}

type Query {
    money(id: Long!): Money
    coin(id: Long!): Coin 
}

type Money {
  id: Long!
  coins: [Coin!]!
}

type Coin {
  id: Long!
  name: String!
  history: [DateVal!]
}

type DateVal {
   date: String!
   val: Long!
}
```

I have two endpoints: `/money` and `/coin`, both of which take an id. When I make a request to `/money` I get back a response like below:

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "coins": [
    { "id" : 1, "name" : "N1", "history": null},
    { "id" : 2, "name" : "N2", "history": null},
  ]  
}
```

If I call the `coin` endpoint with the coin id, I get the full history for the coin.

Is there a way to make GraphQL take a response like this and recursively call the `/coin` endpoint using the id of each coin in order to fill the history? I tried the following the following query but it didn't recursively call the `coin` endpoint.

```
{
  money(id: 1) {
    id
    coins {
      id
      name
      history {
        date
        val
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your resolver functions?

Comment: @AlessanderFrança I found out that my problem was that I did not wire resolver for the `history` field for the `coin`. I assumed (incorrectly) that graphQL would automatically call the `coin` for the coin response.

Comment: Nice! this error is common in graphql.